# Getting the derivative of a function as a function with sympy (for later evaluation and substitution)

Tags: python, sympy

I want to work with generic functions as long as possible, and only substitute functions at the end.
I'd like to define a function as the derivative of another one, define a generic expression with the function and its derivative, and substitute the function at the end.
Right now my attempts is as follows, but I get the error `'Derivative' object is not callable`:

```py
from sympy import Function
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
f  = Function('f') 
df = f(x).diff(x)  # <<< I'd like this to be a function of dummy variable x
expr = f(x) * df(z)  + df(y) + df(0) # df is unfortunately not callable
# At the end, substitute with example function
expr.replace(f, Lambda(X, cos(X))) # should return: -cos(x)*sin(z) - sin(y) - sin(0)
```

I think I got it to work with integrals as follows:
`I= Lambda( x, integrate( f(y), (y, 0, x)))` but that won't work for derivatives.
If that helps, I'm fine restricting myself to functions of a single variable for now.

As a bonus, I'd like to get this to work with any combination (products, derivatives, integrals) of the original function.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty disappointing that `f.diff(x)` doesn't work, as you say. Maybe someone will create support it sometime in the future. In the mean time, there are 2 ways to go about it: either substitute `x` for your `y, z, ...` OR lambdify `df`.

I think the first option will work more consistently in the long run (for example, if you decide to extend to multivariate calculus). But the `expr` in second option is far more natural.

Using substitution:

```py
from sympy import *

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
X = Symbol('X')

f = Function('f')
df = f(x).diff(x)

expr = f(x) * df.subs(x, z) + df.subs(x, y) + df.subs(x, 0)
print(expr.replace(f, Lambda(X, cos(X))).doit())
```

Lambdifying `df`:

```py
from sympy import *

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
X = Symbol('X')

f = Function('f')
df = lambda t: f(t).diff(t) if isinstance(t, Symbol) else f(X).diff(X).subs(X, t)

expr = f(x) * df(z) + df(y) + df(0)
print(expr.replace(f, Lambda(X, cos(X))).doit())
```

Both give the desired output.

Comment: Don't confuse a python `function` (or kambda`) with a `sympy.Function`.  They may all be `callable`, but I doubt if the class `mro` is connected.

Comment: I think for this purpose they are equivalent (I might be mistaken). I just prefer to use the regular `lambda`.  It makes me feel that it's faster since it runs through an if statement instead of parsing a more complex `sympy.Piecewise`.